# Windows 10 shortcut icons are messed up

Tags: windows-10, desktop, shortcuts, github, desktop-icons

I recently encountered a problem with my Windows 10.

My shortcuts are using a different symbol (the down left corner of the shortcut) other than the normal shortcut symbol. The symbol changes from time to time, and some of the time it's the regular shortcut symbol. Sometime when I refresh the desktop it solves it, if not I play with it a little until it goes away, but it keeps comeing back.

It might have to do something with the GitHub for desktop as it's the last thing that I installed on my PC.

Messed up shortcuts:

[image]

How It should be:

[image]

Comment: you somehow managed to commit your entire desktop into a git repository. Lets all hope its a local repo with unpushed commits, otherwise all of your personal data is now publicly available on the internet. You better check the remote of your repo and disconnect it if there is one. Tip : do not use development tools without having the necessary skills. I didnt even know that something like this is possible - congratulations you also managed to astonish an experienced software developer

Comment: That's the first thing I checked lol... That is not the problem man

Comment: its the ONLY problem man. That symbol is either a GIT repository or SVN repository state symbol, especially if it keeps coming back. On your desktop you will find either a .git or a .svn directory - you need to enable the "show hidden files" option in order to see it. Once you delete that directory the symbols wont keep coming back BUT they're still checked in.

Comment: I've already searched for .git/.svn files. And I've looked at my commits in GitHub, and I have not committed my desktop. As I've already mentioned, the symbol is not always the same, for example earlier today it was the shared folder symbol.

Comment: in that case your computer is infected with a trojan horse or virus, the only surefire solution to that is completely formatting your entire drive and re-installing windows.